# Estimating length of an event sampled from an unknown distribution, conditioned on being at least a certain length

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, inference

Consider the following scenario: a person is at a train station waiting for a train. The train arrival times can be represented as a Poisson distribution with unknown $\lambda$. The person has already waited for $x$ seconds. What is the best estimate of how much time the person will continue to wait? We have no prior knowledge about typical train arrival times (it could be once a minute, once a day, once a year, etc).

This scenario presumably has a counterintuitive result: the longer the person has waited, the longer he should expect to keep waiting. Is there a good way to produce an actual estimate of how long he should expect to keep waiting, conditioned on having already waited for $x$ seconds?

Comment: Poisson counting processes arise from independent exponential interarrival times. Exponential rvs have memorylessness. That means conditioning on the arrival time greater than a fixed amount means the new variable is just exponential from there on.

Comment: Perhaps what is counterintuitive is that we have experience waiting for trains and the arrivals *of any particular train* are not a Poisson process; worse, they aren't even decently approximated by a Poisson process.  (Arrivals are too regularly spaced.)